# How to detect if there're more than one html tags in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

We have an aspx page that is embed in an external application, and we recently found they inserted an extra html tag in the page for some cookie reason. There is no way they can remove the tag or fix the problem. I would think if there's any way that I can detect the injected extra html tag from my side so we can do something specific for it.

The final page would look like this:

```
<!--Here is the injected stuff-->
<html>
    <body onfocus="document.cookie='blahblahblah'"></body>
</html>
<!--Below is our original markup-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
      Some content
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried use jQuery selectors and JavaScript document.querySelectorAll to select all the html/body tags but look like they can only find the html/body tag in original markup. They're like

```
$(function(){
  if($('html').length > 1)
    //Do something
  else if(document.querySelectorAll('html').length > 1)
    //Do something
});
```

None of these worked. They always return length = 1 while the browser is giving the following warning message:

> HTML1502: Unexpected DOCTYPE. Only one DOCTYPE is allowed and it must occur before any elements.
>   HTML1513: Extra "<html>" tag found. Only one "<html>" tag should exist per document.

I am wondering if there's any way that I can find this extra tag using JavaScript or can I simulate what the browser did to detect this extra tag.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should **never** need to know if there's more than one `<html>` element in the page as there should only ever be one. More or less than that is invalid. A workaround would be to use an `iframe` to contain the content of the external application. The error you see tells you everything you need to know; one `<html>` tag, and put the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration before everything else in the page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. I know the extra html tag is invalid by any means but the process of adding the extra tag is out of my control. So I'm looking for workarounds on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do that in native Javascript, because the Html DOM Tree can have only one Html tag and it's a convention. 
I think you can do this using a serverSide language.

Something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourscript.yourTechno',
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(result){
        alert('you have '+result+ 'html tags');
    })
})
```

On the server side (with PHP and a dom parser for example)

```
$count = 0;
$html = file_get_html('http://www.myWebSite.com/myPageToParse.html');
foreach($html->find('html') as $element){
    $count ++;
}
echo($count);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/